# share a global variable in multi threading doesn't work in python

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables

I am trying to share a global variable between two function in `python`. They are working at the same time whith multitreading.
the problem is that its like the global variable is not global at all here is my code:

```
import threading as T
import time

nn = False
def f1(inp):
    global nn
    while True:
        inp=inp+1
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print 'a-'+str(inp)+"\n"
        if inp > 10:
            nn=True
            print nn

def f2(inp):
    inp=int(inp)
    while nn:
        inp=inp+1
        time.sleep(1)
        print 'b-'+str(inp)+"\n"

t1= T.Thread(target=f1, args = (1,))
t1.daemon = True
t1.start()
t2= T.Thread(target=f2, args = (1,))
t2.daemon = True
t2.start()
```

Comment: What do you mean they are not global at all?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I meant that it seems to work localy but I found the problem. with answers, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variables work fine in python.

The issue in your code would be that you first start `f1` function , which goes into sleep for 0.5 seconds.

Then immediately after starting f1 , you also start `f2` and then inside that you have the loop - `while nn` - but initial value of f2 is False, hence it never goes into the while loop , and that thread ends.

Are you really expecting the code to take more than 0.5 seconds to reach from start `f1` thread and the `while nn` condition (so that nn can be set to `True` ) ? I think it would not take more than few nano seconds for the program to reach there.

Example of global variables working -

```
>>> import threading
>>> import time
>>> def func():
...     global l
...     i = 0
...     while i < 15:
...             l.append(i)
...             i += 1
...             time.sleep(1)
>>> def foo(t):
...     t.start()
...     i = 20
...     while i > 0:
...             print(l)
...             i -= 1
...             time.sleep(0.5)
>>> l = []
>>> t = threading.Thread(target=func)
>>> foo(t)
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: thanks, and not I tought it will be like: a-1,a-2,a-3...a-9,a-10,b-1,a-11,a-12,b-2...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `while nn` only gets evaluated once. When it is, it happens to be `False` because f1 has not yet made it `True` so `f2` finishes running.  If you initialize `nn = True` you'll see it is being accessed by both `f1` and `f2`